# How to use retry and repeat combined in Reactor?

Tags: project-reactor

I'm polling the queue messages, and I would like to do `retry` if some error happens or `repeat` if I don't receive any messages. The total count of retries and repeats should be equal to `numRetries`. What's the best way to achieve this?

That's what I achieved so far:

```kotlin
Flux.defer { awsSQSClient.receiveMessage(10) }
            .retry(numRetries)
            .repeatWhen { emittedEachAttempt ->
                emittedEachAttempt.handle<Flux<Message>> { lastEmitted, sink ->
                    val ctx = sink.currentContext()
                    val rl = ctx.getOrDefault("repeatsLeft", numRetries)
                    if (rl > 0 && lastEmitted == 0L) {
                        sink.next(Context.of("repeatsLeft", rl - 1)) // <-- This line doesn't compile although I copied it from reactor documentation
                    } else {
                        sink.next(Flux.empty())
                    }

                }
            }
```

I'm struggling with `repeatWhen` lambda, and I also don't understand how to couple `retry`, and `repeat` counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to do retry if some error happens or repeat if I don't receive any messages.

It doesn't make much sense to differentiate between retries and repeats here, particularly as you want to keep track of the total repeats / retries collectively. Both operators will essentially do the same thing (re-subscribe to the source publisher), it's just that they do so under different circumstances.

You'd be much better to use:

```
.switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException()))
```

...above your retry line, then scrap the `repeatWhen()` section entirely. You can then just set `numRetries()` to the total number of retries / repeats you want.

(You may also want to use a more appropriate exception type in real-world use of course.)

Comment: Very elegant solution! Worked for me, thanks!